# MAX(), but only if all values are not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-view

In SQL Server 2016, I have a table that looks something like this:

**dbo.jobs**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | First Job |
| 1 | Second Job |

**dbo.tasks**

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-3 |
| 1 | 2017-04-02 | 2017-04-4 |
| 2 | 2017-04-03 | null |

**dbo.job_tasks**

| id | job_id | task_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

What I'm attempting to do, is to create a view that contains the jobs, with the lowest start and highest end date of the tasks reflecting the start and end date of the jobs.  That's relatively easy, with a query in the view like this:

```sql
SELECT
   jobs.id,
   jobs.name,
   MIN(tasks.start_date) as job_start_date,
   MAX(task.end_date) as job_end_date,
FROM
   jobs
   LEFT OUTER JOIN job_tasks on jobs.id = job_tasks.job_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks on job_tasks.task_id = tasks.task_id
GROUP BY jobs.id, jobs.name, job_tasks.job_id, job_tasks.task_id, tasks.task_id
```

The result from this would look like:

| id | name | job_start_date | job_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | First Job | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-3 |
| 1 | Second Job | 2017-04-02 | 2017-04-4 |

However, if there's a task that has a null end_date, as in the case of the "Second Job", that task isn't completed - so the job_end_date should actually be null, and the correct output would be like this:

| id | name | job_start_date | job_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | First Job | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-3 |
| 1 | Second Job | 2017-04-02 | null |

All the aggregate functions ignore null, except for COUNT(). So, my thought at the moment is to use a table valued function, and pass in the job_id. That would limit the scope of the data being processed, and allow me to check for the null end dates and adjust accordingly with a CASE statement. Something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @completed bit
SET @completed = 1

IF EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM job_tasks 
   INNER JOIN tasks on tasks.task_id = job_tasks.task_id AND tasks.end_date IS NULL
   WHERE job_tasks.task_id = @taskId
)
BEGIN
   SET @completed = 0
END

SELECT 
  jobs.id,
  jobs.name,
  MIN(tasks.start_date) as job_start_date,
  CASE WHEN @completed = 0 THEN NULL
  ELSE (MAX(tasks.end_date)) END AS job_end_date
FROM
   jobs
   ... joins and group by clause
WHERE jobs.id = @jobId
```

Would there be a better approach to getting this view of the data? Perhaps a way to keep the view, without totally compromising performance?

Any advice would be appreciated.

(view and function boilerplate left out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT jobs.id, jobs.name,
       MIN(tasks.start_date) as job_start_date,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(task.end_date) = COUNT(*)
             THEN MAX(task.end_date)
        END) as job_end_date
```

Comment: This would only work, I think, in the function - where the query is limited to the single jobs.id - as otherwise the count(*) wouldn't take into account the fact that we're dealing with all records. Would have to benchmark it against the variable to see which would actually be faster with my actual data.

Comment: @Mark `COUNT(*)` would be against a single grouping, which in your case is a single `job`

Answer (score 2):

You could use COALESCE and a big date and a case to translate it back to null, something like

```
SELECT id, name, job_start_date,
    (CASE WHEN job_end_date <> {d '2100-01-01'}
         THEN job_end_date
    END) as job_end_date
FROM
(SELECT
   jobs.id,
   jobs.name,
   MIN(tasks.start_date) as job_start_date,
   MAX(COALESCE(task.end_date,{d '2100-01-01'} )) as job_end_date,
FROM
   jobs
   LEFT OUTER JOIN job_tasks on jobs.id = job_tasks.job_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks on job_tasks.task_id = tasks.task_id
GROUP BY jobs.id, jobs.name, job_tasks.job_id, job_tasks.task_id, tasks.task_id) A
```

This can also be done without the subselect, but it's harder to read and write...

Comment: This is an interesting approach, which has the benefit of working in the view, not requiring a function.  I'd probably go with '9999-12-31' as the high date value, just because that's the max date in SQL Server.  Thanks!